# Meshlab 2020.03 - Point picking within a face

Tags: meshlab

The PP (Pick Points) tool (in v. 2016) allowed to select multiple points of the mesh and see their XYZ coordinates. The new version does not have this tool. I can use the yellow information button "i" to see the coordinates of a vertex, but not a point within a face. Is there any way to see these coordinates?

Comment: Thanks a lot for recovering the "PickPoints" tool in the last version (2020.07). It's a really useful tool in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

To get the coords of a point over a surface remember that *double click* recenters the trackball ***and*** prints in the log window the coords of the clicked point

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ALoopingIcon for your reply. This way doesn't allow me to export a list of coordinates of previously marked points as before, but at least I can extract the coordinates point by point.